# Regex match outer nested tags

Tags: regex

I have this string

`blabla [IC="test"]Hello, [IC="testing"] this is a nested tag [EC], cya.[EC] blabla`

I'm trying to match the outer `[IC="..."]...[EC]` so I can get

`[IC="test"]Hello, [IC="testing"] this is a nested tag [EC], cya.[EC]`

I currently have this

`\[IC=\"([\s\S]*?)\"]([\s\S]*?)\[EC]\n{0,1}`

But its not matching it until the last closing tag `[EC]`

This is an example of my code on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/VIGwMg/1)

Comment: What language/flavour/engine?

Comment: I'm not much into RegEx but I'm using it in an iOS app using objc.

Comment: How about a recursive pattern? https://regex101.com/r/rlUHeZ/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a recursive pattern (supported in `PCRE`):

```
\[IC[^][]*\]
(?:(?:[^][]*|(?R))*)
\[EC\]
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/t0G3pR/1/).

Comment: Thanks! I modified the code a bit so it supports line breaks and captures some parts. `\[IC="([\s\S]*?)"\]((?:(?:[^][]*|(?R))*))\[EC\]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(\[IC="\w*"\].*\[EC\])
```

https://regex101.com/r/MVU9ni/1

Matches 0 or more characters that are located in between `[IC="any_word_character_here"]` and `[EC]`.

Answer (score 1):

I dont get your decision to use the `\s\S` and it just seems more confusing than it really should be. 
However to fix the issue you are having simply remove the `?`

```
...([\s\S]*?)\[EC]...
```

to

```
...([\s\S]*)\[EC]...
```

resulting into

```
\[IC=\"([\s\S]*?)\"]([\s\S]*)\[EC]\n{0,1}
```

however i would simply use `\w` and `.*` because they are easier

```
\[IC="(\w*)"\](.*)\[EC\]
```

EDIT:

Working off of the assumption that you actually need to get the string value from [IC=".."] and string inbetween. otherwise if you just need whole data then no need for the groupings

```
\[IC="\w*"\].*\[EC\]
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer works as well! I'm using \s\S in order to support line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression below should do the trick:

```
[^\[]*(\[.*\])[^\]]*
```

You can try a working demo visiting [this link](https://regex101.com/r/uQoOkp/1).

Alternatively, if you don't want to rely on capturing groups, this should be enough:

```
(\[.*\])
```

A working demo of the regular expression above can be tested [here](https://regex101.com/r/rWwAuu/1).