# regex to match othermost tags (string pair)

Tags: r, regex, latex, r-markdown, pandoc

I have a book that was written in Sweave and contains a lot of Latex that I am trying to convert to Rmarkdown. I have managed to write a script that converts most of the Latex to reasonable markdown but nested lists eludes me.

My idea so far is to detect when a list starts and ends and then pass it onto pandoc for conversion since I think making a parser would be make it unnecessarily difficult.
The problem is detecting where the list starts and ends when the list is nested.

I found an example of matching bracketed tags here but I haven't been able to figure out how to convert it to match \begin and \end. ([Regex match outer nested tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48132704/regex-match-outer-nested-tags))

Example data:

```
meh meh

\begin{itemize}
\item something1
\begin{itemize}
\item something1.1
\item something1.2
\end{itemize}
\item something2
\begin{itemize}
\item something2.1

\item something2.2
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

blah blah

\begin{itemize}
\item somethingelse1
\item somethingelse2
\end{itemize}

the end.
```

There should be two matches above. One for the nested list and one for the below list.
Can this be done with a regex or do you see some smarter way?

Comment: [there was a removed Q about whether I had looked at existing parsers] Yes, there is pandoc that can be called through knitr or rmarkdown (though I used it directly to have more control) to convert latex to markdown. The problem is that I don't want to parse the whole document to keep control. For example I am converting `includegraphics` and `tikzpicture` to code chunks.

Comment: You may add it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex that matches recursively between `\begin{...}` and `\end{...}` is a PCRE regex like

```r
(?s)\\begin\{[^{}]*}(?:(?!\\(?:end|begin)).|(?R))*\\end\{[^{}]*}
```

A more efficient version of the regex (unrolled one, I also added a check for `{` after `\begin` and `\end` in the lookahead) is:

```r
\\begin\{[^{}]*}(?:[^\\]*(?:\\(?!(?:end|begin)\{)[^\\]*)*|(?R))*\\end\{[^{}]*}
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/hKl3Jo/1/) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/hKl3Jo/3). *Details*:

- `(?s)` - a singleline/dotall/`s` modifier that makes `.` match across line breaks
- `\\begin\{` - `\begin{` string
- `[^{}]*` - zero or more chars other than `{` and `}`
- `}` - a `}` char
- `(?:(?!\\(?:end|begin)).|(?R))*` - zero or more occurrences, as many as possible, of

  - `(?!\\(?:end|begin)).` - any one char that does not start a `\end` or `\begin` char sequence
  - `|` - or
  - `(?R)` - the whole regex pattern is recursed
- `\\end\{` - `\end{` string
- `[^{}]*}` - zero or more chars other than `{` and `}` and then a `}` char.

Sample R code:

```r
x <- "meh meh\n\\begin{itemize}\n\\item something1\n\\begin{itemize}\n\\item something1.1\n\\item something1.2\n\\end{itemize}\n\\item something2\n\\begin{itemize}\n\\item something2.1\n\\item something2.2\n\\end{itemize}\n\\end{itemize}\nblah blah\n\\begin{itemize}\n\\item somethingelse1\n\\item somethingelse2\n\\end{itemize}\nthe end.\n"
reg <- "(?s)\\\\begin\\{[^{}]*}(?:(?!\\\\(?:end|begin)).|(?R))*\\\\end\\{[^{}]*}"
## reg2 <- "\\\\begin\\{[^{}]*}(?:[^\\\\]*(?:\\\\(?!(?:end|begin)\\{)[^\\\\]*)*|(?R))*\\\\end\\{[^{}]*}"
result <- regmatches(x, gregexpr(reg, x, perl=TRUE))
```

Output:

```
> result
[[1]]
[1] "\\begin{itemize}\n\\item something1\n\\begin{itemize}\n\\item something1.1\n\\item something1.2\n\\end{itemize}\n\\item something2\n\\begin{itemize}\n\\item something2.1\n\\item something2.2\n\\end{itemize}\n\\end{itemize}"
[2] "\\begin{itemize}\n\\item somethingelse1\n\\item somethingelse2\n\\end{itemize}"
```

Comment: Fantastic! This seem to do the trick perfectly. Very grateful for the fast help.

Comment: @JanStanstrup I added a faster regex version.

Comment: Great! based on your line I expanded to only match itemize and enumerate so it doesn't match all other things like `\center{   }`. --> `.*\\\\begin\\{[^{}]*(?:itemize|enumerate)}(?:[^\\\\]*(?:\\\\(?!(?:end|begin)\\{)[^\\\\]*)*|(?R))*\\\\end\\{[^{}]*(?:itemize|enumerate)}` . Note escaped as needed for R.